# Trying to print out my blog posts horizontally on the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, alignment

I've tried to print them as columns, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how best to accomplish this??

```
<div class="post-block">
  <div v-for="(post,index) in posts" :key="post.slug + '_' + index">
    <router-link :to="'/blog/' + post.slug">
      <article class="media">
        <figure>
          <div class="posts"> 
            <img v-if="post.featured_image" :src="post.featured_image" alt="" style="max-width:25%;">
            <img v-else src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </article>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</div>

  .post-block {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #151515;
    position: relative;
  }

  p, h2 {
    color:#D3D3D3;
  }
```

Comment: Without any accompanying CSS it's not possible to see what's wrong with your code. Also... why are you testing entire post contents inside a `<figure>` element?

Comment: @Terry I've added the small css I have on there. The figure element is there is case of any photos being added to the the blog post. Do I not need it?

Comment: You are not using `post-block` class anywhere. Also, its not a good idea to show all posts horizontally.. maybe 3 posts per row in a large screen, then 2 then 1.. as screen becomes small?

Comment: @palaѕн That would be what I'm looking for, yes. I cut off the code before then. It's fixed now

Comment: @palaѕн I'm using bootstrap-vue, but could easily switch to bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to update CSS like to create a responsive layout. Please update color scheme based on your requirement. Just sharing the basic layout you can use and update as needed:

```
.post-block {
  color: #151515;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-block>div {
  flex: 1 0 calc(26% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #84613D;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background: #FDF9EA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
  border-right: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
}
.post-block .posts {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .post-block>div {
    flex-basis: calc(34% - 10px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .post-block>div {
    flex-basis: calc(51% - 10px);
  }
}

p,
h2 {
  color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ltjdear/) ( <sub>*Please resize the result window to see the responsive layout*</sub> )

Comment: @palash I see how you did that. That works perfectly. Thank you!